# How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-dependencies

My gradle project uses the `application` plugin to build a jar file. As part of the runtime transitive dependencies, I end up pulling in `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12`. (It's referenced as a sub-transitive dependency in at least 5 or 6 other transitive dependencies - this project is using spring and hadoop, so everything but the kitchen sink is getting pulled in... no wait... that's there too :) ).

I want to globally exclude the `slf4j-log4j12` jar from my built jar. So I've tried this:

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

However, this seems to exclude **all** `org.slf4j` artifacts including `slf4j-api`. When running under debug mode I see lines such as:

```
org.slf4j#slf4j-api is excluded from com.pivotal.gfxd:gfxd-demo-mapreduce:1.0(runtime).
org.slf4j#slf4j-simple is excluded from com.pivotal.gfxd:gfxd-demo-mapreduce:1.0(runtime).
org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12 is excluded from org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.2.0(runtime).
```

I do not want to have to look up the source of each `slf4j-log4j12` transitive dependency and then have individual `compile foo { exclude slf4j... }` statements in my `dependencies` block.

**Update:**

I did also try this:

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude name: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

Which ends up excluding **everything** from the build! As though I specified `group: "*"`.

**Update 2:**

I'm using Gradle version 1.10 for this.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Ah, the following works and does what I want:

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

It seems that an [Exclude Rule](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExcludeRule.html) only has two attributes - `group` and `module`.
Hence for excluding from only an individual dependency, we can do something like:

```
dependencies {
  compile ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-core:2.0.0.M4-hadoop22') {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
  }
}
```

---

However, the above syntax doesn't prevent you from specifying any arbitrary property as a predicate. When trying to exclude from an individual dependency you cannot specify arbitrary properties. For example, this fails:

```
dependencies {
  compile ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-core:2.0.0.M4-hadoop22') {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-log4j12"
  }
}
```

with

```
No such property: name for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule
```

So even though you can specify a dependency with a `group:` and `name:` you can't specify an exclusion with a `name:`!?!

Perhaps a separate question, but what **exactly** is a *module* then? I can understand the Maven notion of groupId:artifactId:version, which I understand translates to group:name:version in Gradle. But then, how do I know what module (in gradle-speak) a particular Maven artifact belongs to?

Comment: This seems like better discussion for the [Gradle forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle).

Comment: So done - http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/what_exactly_is_a_module_as_defined_by_gradle_dependencies

Comment: Ugh, I just struggled with this exact issue. I find it so exceptionally difficult to do anything with gradle, especially resolve conflicts on a large project. I'd happily take verbose xml with xsd validation over gradle's dsl

Comment: The "name:" should be "module:", then it will work for u :)

Comment: For the benefit of future me and others, I wanted to exclude ALL dependency libraries (Gradle 3.3) from my war package. So rather than list out each one, I simply did `configurations { runtime.exclude group: '*' }`.

Comment: there is no name object, I had to use `module`. example : `exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j", module: "log4j-slf4j-impl"`

Comment: Type com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod is defined multiple times
How can I solve this

Comment: this can still cause an issue if other dependencies have same transitive dependency, use configuration exclude instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968390/4781155

Answer (score 77):

For excluding one or more library globally add the following to your build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
   exclude group:"org.apache.geronimo.specs", module: "geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec"
   exclude group:"ch.qos.logback", module:"logback-core"
}
```

Now the exclude block has two properties **group** and **module**. For those of you coming from maven background, **group** is same as **groupId** and **module** is same as **artifactId**.
Example: To exclude com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.2.1 following should be exclude block

```
exclude group:"com.mchange", module:"c3p0"
```

Answer (score 35):

Your approach is correct. (Depending on the circumstances, you might want to use `configurations.all { exclude ... }`.) If these excludes really exclude more than a single dependency (I haven't ever noticed that when using them), please file a bug at http://forums.gradle.org, ideally with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 29):

in the example below I exclude

> spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
     //by both name and group
     exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' 
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I was using spring boot 1.5.10 and tries to exclude logback, the given solution above did not work well, I use configurations instead

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module:"spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`compile` is deprecated and it was replaced by `implementation`. Therefore, the solution for those running newer versions of gradle:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
     exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what @berguiga-mohamed-amine stated, I just found that a wildcard requires leaving the module argument the empty string:

```
compile ("com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:$jsonldJavaVersion") {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: ''
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: ''
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**) which prevents you from using wrong properties.

Exclude the library from all configrations (`implementation`, `runtimeOnly`, etc.):

```kotlin
configurations.all {
    exclude(group = "ir.mahozad.android", module = "pie-chart")
    // OR exclude("ir.mahozad.android", "pie-chart")
}

// Another notation:
// configurations {
//     all {
//         exclude(group = "ir.mahozad.android", module = "pie-chart")
//     }
// }
```

Exclude the library from a single configuration (like `implementation`):

```kotlin
configurations.implementation {
    exclude(group = "ir.mahozad.android", module = "pie-chart")
}

// Another notation:
// configurations {
//     implementation {
//         exclude(group = "ir.mahozad.android", module = "pie-chart")
//     }
// }
```

Exclude the library for a single dependency:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation("ir.mahozad.android:charts:1.2.3") {
        exclude(group = "ir.mahozad.android", module = "pie-chart")
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `configureEach` instead of `all` to avoid unnecessary configuration