# Disable Logback in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

It appears Springboot autoconfigures itself to use Logback with Tomcat. I would like to disable this and use the one I provide in my classpath.

The error message below.

> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
>   classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
>   (class org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory) Object of class
>   [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.fe</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Withinet-PaaS</name>
    <description>Develop your web applications in on our infrastructure and we will worry about administration and scalability of your app.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <guava.version>16.0.1</guava.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.withinet.cloudapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>slave</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate validator -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>


        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Guava -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Security 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.withinet.cloud.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Add exclusion to both the spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-web to resolve the conflict.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because if I add those exclusions I get: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`.

Comment: Once you do this you will have to provide your own logger e.g log4j in your classpath. Why do you wish to exclude the default loggers from you application?

Comment: Is there a way to find out which jar declares logback without doing some 'exploration' in each jar? And, thanks! This helped me

Comment: mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-boot-starter-logging

Comment: having to add this exclusion to each spring-boot-starter-* dependency is a huge hassle. It seems like Gradle at least allows a global exclusion. This alone is seriously making me consider switching from Maven.

Comment: I've done this but still finding additional SLF4J bindings in the classpath

Comment: It worked! i was using slf4j explicitly and springboot's default logging was clashing with the slf4j and throws same exception. So had to exclude defaults.

Comment: In my case (using a custom `assembly` build instead of the Boot Maven plugin) the exclusions didn't work for some reason - ended up excluding `ch.qos.logback:*` artifacts from the assembly XML itself

Answer (score 87):

To add a better, more generic solution in Gradle (all instances will be excluded):

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

From https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: That works for me and at least 7 other people.  I don't think a problem with your configuration or environment should be a downvote for my solution (I assumed the downvote i received was from your comment - apologies if I'm wrong).

Comment: This doesn't work, I still see `spring-boot-starter-logging`

Comment: This worked for me. Now gradle is able to run the tests without that log-related error.

Answer (score 47):

To add a solution in gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {
        exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Correct way to exclude default logging, and configure log4j for logging.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Refer [Spring Logging - How To](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

In gradle, I needed to do this with several other dependencies:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
}
```

Comment: This should be considered the correct answer, and devs that land here should really think hard about which of these answers to follow. This answer cites the current spring boot docs, while many of he other answers are some form of "this is what worked for me". I would say that if one does what the Spring Boot docs say and it doesn't work, to look closely at your maven dependencies and figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Yes, because if you don't exclude "spring-boot-starter-logging" from "spring-boot-starter" specifically it will likely still find a way to get into your jars from some other Spring starter

Answer (score 19):

I found that excluding the full `spring-boot-starter-logging` module is not necessary. All that is needed is to exclude the `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` module.

Adding this to a Gradle build file will resolve the issue:

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    compile.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

See this other StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle) for more details.

Answer (score 13):

For gradle,

You can see this solution at: http://www.idanfridman.com/how-to-exclude-libraries-from-dependcies-using-gradle/

Just need add `exclude` in `configurations`:

```
configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude(group: 'ch.qos.logback')
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It might help if you say what your preferred logger is exactly, and what you did to try and install it. Anyway, Spring Boot tries to work with whatever is in the classpath, so if you don't want logback, take it off the classpath. There are instructions for log4j [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging), but the same thing would apply to other supported logging systems (anything slf4j, log4j or java util).

Comment: I use slf4j and I can't see logback in my maven pom file.

Comment: Logback *is* an slf4j logger. Maybe you can share your pom?

Comment: I can't see any other slf4j implementations explicitly, so it must be coming in transitively. You can use tools like m2e (Eclipse) or "mvn dependency:tree" to visualize the dependencies. The Eclipse tooling also has a GUI for excluding dependencies (that's what you need to do - exclude one of them). It might be suffient to exclude "spring-boot-starter-logging" if you already have a complete slf4j (including the jcl bridge).

Answer (score 12):

I do like this to solve my problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Find spring-boot-starter-test in your pom.xml and modify it as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It fixed error like:

```
_Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:_ **LoggerFactory** is not a **Logback LoggerContext** but *Logback* is on the classpath.

Either remove **Logback** or the competing implementation

(_class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory_
loaded from file: 

**${M2_HOME}/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.6.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar**).

If you are using WebLogic you will need to add **'org.slf4j'** to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: **org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory**
```

Answer (score 8):

Following works for me

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: With this I was still seeing the logback JARs in the final artifact (was using Assembly plugin instead of Boot's Maven plugin - so not sure if it actually works with Boot packaging)

Answer (score 8):

Same problem for me.

[image]

If you are using `log4j2`

In the Spring boot `2.4.0`

I **resolve** below,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId> <-- exclude this artifactId
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After, Maven Build > Clean > Run

[image]

Work for me.

Comment: why do you exclude log4j slf4j instead of logback classic?

Answer (score 7):

I resolved my problem through this below:

```
compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.0'){
    exclude module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
    exclude module: 'logback-classic'
}
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
    exclude module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
    exclude module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was only required to exclude the `spring-boot-starter-logging` artifact from the `spring-boot-starter-security` one.

This is in a newly generated spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE project including the following dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-security
- spring-boot-starter-validation
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-test

I found out by running `mvn dependency:tree` and looking for  `ch.qos.logback`.

The spring boot related `<dependencies>` in my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>           
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

Comment: It worked after excluding spring-boot-starter-logging

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me just fine

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

But it wouldn't work out for **maven** users. All my dependencies was in libs.gradle and I didn't want them in other files. So this **problem was solved** by adding `exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging` in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, `spring-boot-starter-test` and in practically everything with boot word.

**UPDATE**

New project of mine needed an update, turns out `spring-boot-starter-test` 1.5 and older didn't have `spring-boot-starter-logging`. 2.0 has it

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Gradle** & **Lombok**, here is the simplest configuration for **Log4j2** that worked for me using the latest Spring Boot (2.4.1 at this time) :

#### build.gradle  (partial)

```
configurations {
    compileOnly { extendsFrom annotationProcessor }
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // (*** other dependencies ***)

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I noticed you will get errors if you include `spring-bbot-starter-log4j2` as a `compileOnly` dependency instead of as an `implementation`.

Just annotate your classes with `@Log4j2` (or `@Slf4j`) and lombok will make available a `log` variable you can use for logging.

As usual, provide a `log4j2.xml` configuration file in your `/src/main/resources` folder.

Answer (score 2):

If this error occurred in SpringBoot when you are trying to use log4j2 then
do these steps:

- Remove the jar from while packeging by adding this "excludeGroupIds log4j-slf4j-impl  /excludeGroupIds"
- Find out the which library is depends on "logback-classic" by using command "mvn dependecy:tree"
- Wherever you find it exclude it from the dependency.

This error occurred because logback override the log4j2 changes. SO if you want to use log4j2 then you have to remove logback library and dependencies.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just add logback.xml configuration in your classpath and add all your configuration with root appender added. Once the Spring boot completes the bean loading, it will start logging based on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To add an exclusion for logback from Netbeans IDE

1. Access the >*Projects explorer* section for your project
2. Proceed to >*Dependencies* as displayed below
3. Trace 'spring-boot-starter-logging-X.X.X.jar'
4. Right click on the jar and select *Exclude Dependency* as shown below. This excludes the logback jar on the pom.xml like this;

   ```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case below exclusion works!!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-web-util</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding exclusions was not enough for me. I had to provide a fake jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/empty.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, spring boot comes with logback as its default log configuration whereas camel uses log4j. Thats the reason of conflict. You have two options, either remove logback from spring boot as mentioned in above answers or remove log4j from camel.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disable spring boot starter logging**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>                                               
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>         
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**Disable LogBack OR Log4j From Spring Boot Starter**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>                                  
            <exclusion>                                     
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>         
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>             
            </exclusion>
    
            <exclusion>                                     
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>               
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>     
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to outline the dependency relationship between dependencies. Then, identify under which dependency `ch.qos.logback` falls as a transitive dependency. If it's under dependency A, simply exclude the logback package in A's Maven config using .