# Spring boot application does not start after adding pubnub in maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pubnub

My Spring boot application does not start after i add pubnub in maven.

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pubnub/pubnub -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pubnub</groupId>
            <artifactId>pubnub</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.XXX.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>smartSense</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <name>XXX</name>
    <description>smartSense Construction ERP</description>
</project>
```

I got this exception while running spring boot jar

Exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/home/nitin/projects/bitbucket/cerp/target/cerp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:346)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.cerp.Application.main(Application.java:89)
    ... 8 more
```

I building micro service for real time web application, I want to use pubnub for sending notification to web browser.
If i removed pubnub then it works fine.
Can you please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: See this older SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems pubnub has a transitive dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

if you add an exclusion to your pubnub dependency (see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)) it may already work. But maybe this breaks the logging in pubnub :/ - but I would give it a try.