# Wildfly 10 no logs after spring-boot-starter-logging exclusion

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, war, wildfly-10

I'm developing web application in Spring Boot packed in WAR file and developed on Wildfly 10. 
Because of problem with conflicted Logging classes I had to excluse `spring-boot-starter-logging`as was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991715 using following code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Now, application deploys successfuly, but in Wildfly logs I see only 
`ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined` 
error message instead of debug/info informations about deployment.

How to fix Wildfly logs?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?