# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings - Spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, logback, slf4j, jhipster

I have a spring boot starter project and I want to add a dependency from an external jar. I add the jar to maven using `mvn install:install-file` and I added the dependency to my pom.xml.

After adding the dependency and building the project I get the following error:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/hubtech/hubpipeline/1.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [consoleAppender] to category [root].
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/hubtech/hubpipeline/1.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:389)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:274)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at com.hubtech.HubTechApp.main(HubTechApp.java:66)
```

I looked at all the questions regarding this subject on stackoverflow but nothing resolved my problem.

In my pom.xml I have this new dependecy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hubtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>hubpipeline</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I would like to exclude from the newly added jar the conflicting dependencies. 
But anything I do doesn't change the error.

My project was generated using jhipster and uses LogBack for logging.

Comment: Litteraly the first answer on Google:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot

Comment: Something is strange in your .m2 repository. A sl4j implementation seems present at `.m2/repository/com/hubtech/hubpipeline/1.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar`. However a normal M2 repository should not have a `lib/` folder or any other folder under a project version... What command did you use to install your `hubpipeline` artifact? 
Also how are you building your project, from the IDE or directly from command line? Please include your entire pom.xml, other dependencies or config may also cause your issue.

Comment: how is this question related to jhipster?