# Running Spring Cloud Contract test in non-Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I have created a Spring Cloud Contract stub in a Spring Boot project (`spring-server`). The client that wants to call this stub is not a Spring project and cannot be one. If I run the following in the client:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"uk.co.hadoopathome:spring-server:+:stubs:8093"},
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
public class ContractTest {
    @Test
    public void testContractEndpoint() {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8093/ac01");
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            String entity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            assertEquals("ac01returned", entity);
            response.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

then I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

Obviously I don't have a `@SpringBootConfiguration`, as this isn't a Spring Boot project.

What's the workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Junit rule and you won't have to setup a context

```
public class JUnitTest {

    @Rule public StubRunnerRule rule = new StubRunnerRule()
            .downloadStub("com.example","beer-api-producer")
            .withPort(6543)
            .workOffline(true);

    @Test
    public void should_work() {
        String response = new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://localhost:6543/status", String.class);

        BDDAssertions.then(response).isEqualTo("ok");
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please? I found https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/#_alternative_using_junit_rules, but you have to create your own stubs in the client code, which isn't what I'm looking for here.

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_stub_runner_junit_rule and samples and https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerControllerWithJUnitTest.java we really invest time in the docs but you have to check the latest release train

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The docs are very good, I was just unlucky with my Ctrl+F's :)

Comment: I'm implementing it right now and will mark when it's green.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerControllerWithJUnitTest.java still requires the `RunWith(SpringRunner)` and `SpringBootTest` annotations, and so I get my original error unless I make the change I mention in my answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't require springboottest. If i have it in the sample then it's wrong. You don't need a spring runner either. You just need a normal junit test

Comment: It does work if all class-level annotations from https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerControllerWithJUnitTest.java are removed. I also dont use `MockMvc`.

Comment: Great! Do i guess we can mark it as resolved. I will add an issue to remove the unnecessary annotations

Comment: It would be great to have a working example as the answer; at the moment it's just a one-liner which is probably a bit too short to help other people in the future. I tried to add my working code as an edit but it was rejected. If you copy and paste the documentation code when the issue is resolved, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I've editted the answer. I can't modify the samples cause they combine the JUnit rule to download the stubs and the usage of mock mvc to test the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `@SpringBootTest` line:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ContractTest.class)
```

and then got some Logback errors which I resolved by [finding this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706816/729819) and adding to `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```