# Suddenly getting "LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath." and fails to run

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I use gradle and `latest.release` everywhere to be promiscuous, however, recently my Spring boot application stopped running from command line. When I run `gradle clean bootRun` I get...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/110cefe2df103412849d72ef7a67e4e91e4266b4/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot) I tried...

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
    exclude group: "org.slf4j"
}
```

and that silences the Logback error but spring won't start and fails with no error.

> Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I had this and fixed it by excluding `spring-boot-starter-logging` and `logback-classic` and adding spring log4j2 implementation in `gradle.build`

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.2.6.RELEASE'
```

Comment: I have faced the exact same issue and have tried the above steps. But I see the following error : ERROR 23048 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter                                                        ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:58)

Comment: sounds like you need to check the dependency version numbers in your `gradle.build`

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I have a lot of dependencies, so which version should I check? I am new to Gradle and Spring, so do not have a great idea

Comment: "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist" is the clue. That there is some version conflict. Are you using 2.2.6.RELEASE for log4j2 or another version?

Comment: Yes I am using the exact same version you mentioned above. My Spring cloud context is using 2.2.0.RELEASE and Spring framework security is using 1.0.0.RELEASE. Lombok is 1.18.20

Comment: I am afraid you will have to play around with the versions until you fix the "An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist". I suggest look at [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2) for each of your dependencies and update them all to the latest version. For example now use log4j2 2.4.5 version. Then work backwards if there are still conflicts. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, will check accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove.. `compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:latest.release'`

Haven't figured out through why.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot automatically configures the Log Back library because of the web starter. You should exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging to fix the issue.

To exclude the default LogBack configuration on the gradle project,

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
}
```

You can also try [module replacement](https://tedblob.com/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath/) to replace the LogBack to Log4j or Log4j2