# How to exclude dependency with classifier (platform version) in Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

In my project I have dependency on 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:0.6.0' which brings me transitive dependencies:

- Gradle: org.nd4j:nd4j-native:linux-ppc64le:0.6.0
- Gradle: org.nd4j:nd4j-native:macosx-x86_64:0.6.0
- Gradle: org.nd4j:nd4j-native:windows-x86_64:0.6.0
- Gradle: org.nd4j:nd4j-native:linux-x86_64:0.6.0

I want to exclude nd4j-native:linux-ppc64le and nd4j-native:macosx-x86_64 since my application does not support these platforms. I write in my Gradle file:

```
configurations {
    all.collect { configuration ->
        configuration.exclude(group: 'org.nd4j', module: 'nd4j-native', classifier: 'linux-ppc64le')
    }
}
```

Gradle says:

> Error:(44, 0) Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule.

It seems that gradle does not support exclusion by classifier.

How to exclude such a transitive dependencies?

Update: Gradle allows us to exclude dependencies, but what if we have several dependencies with the same id and group but different classifiers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This topic is about concrete problem with dependencies with classifier.

Comment: @jreznot did you find solution?

Comment: @VadimEksler seems like gradle does not support this

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issued. I have used a deeplearning4j library with Gradle dependency.

```
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '1.0.0-beta'
compile group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta'
```

When I use this it is also downloading other platform classifiers and its size is almost **500MB**. but my use case is specific to the Windows platform so i don't need other classifiers for Linux and Android and other platforms.If I exclude the group it is also excluding the classifier for the windows also . And in Gradle as of my knowledge, we can not exclude specific classifiers.

So the question was how to remove the specific classifier. What I found strange is when I made jar file of the project and extracted jar it shows me the `org.nd4j:nd4j-native:linux-ppc64le:0.6.0` and other jars but when I generate dependency tree it is not showing me the specific jar in the tree.

So in order to find out in which specific module and project the jar is coming from I made a separate maven project and with this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

and then I have  generated a dependency tree. It showed me the jars in the dependency tree.
What I did is I have removed the whole module and I have added the required classifier in a particular module with a **specific version** and it worked for me.

```
compile (group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta') 
{
exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'opencv-platform'
exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'leptonica-platform'
exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'hdf5-platform'

}
compile (group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native-platform', version: '1.0.0-beta')
{
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'openblas-platform'
}

compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta', classifier: "windows-x86_64"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.2.20-1.4.1'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.2.20-1.4.1', classifier: "windows-x86"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.2.20-1.4.1', classifier: "windows-x86_64"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.1-1.4.1'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.1-1.4.1',classifier: "windows-x86"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.1-1.4.1',classifier: "windows-x86_64"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.75.3-1.4.1'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.75.3-1.4.1',classifier: "windows-x86"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.75.3-1.4.1',classifier: "windows-x86_64"
```

Doing this reduced my jar size to almost **250MB**

Answer (score 2):

> How to exclude such a transitive dependencies?

I think, the only way is to exclude all transitive dependencies by it's module or group and manually provide dependencies on libraries for platforms your application supports. Because classifiers are supported in dependency declaration.

And the same way you can handle the case, when you have a number of dependencies with the same module and grooup, but with different classifiers. Just add such dependencies manually with it's classifier property.