# Exclude fourth party dependency with classifier in gradle

Tags: gradle, jar, build.gradle

my question is regarding the exclusion of a fourth party dependency using gradle.

```
compile("org.nd4j:nd4j-native:123") {
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'openblas'
}
compile("org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:openblas:123}:linux-x86_64")
```

With this approach, it makes javacpp-presets a third-party instead of a fourth-party. So, would it be possible to exclude the different other native-platforms from nd4j-native using classifier in gradle (or by employing any gradle plugins)?

Comment: I have answered the question on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319970/how-to-exclude-dependency-with-classifier-platform-version-in-gradle/59451395#59451395). It meight be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per the guide at https://deeplearning4j.org/android, for example, this is how we do can do this in the case of ND4J:

```
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3'
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-arm"
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-arm64"
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-x86"
compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.0-1.4.2'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.0-1.4.2', classifier: "android-arm"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.0-1.4.2', classifier: "android-arm64"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.0-1.4.2', classifier: "android-x86"
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.0-1.4.2', classifier: "android-x86_64"
```

Here binaries for no other platforms than Android will get included.