# butter knife not compatible with appcompat:v7:24.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

HI am about to use butterknif in my project but it gave me an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0rBn.png)

Comment: u can exclude some appcompat by libaray form butter knife eg  compile('us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'espresso-core'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'design'
    }

Comment: please add you `build.gradle` file

Comment: This issue is due to the mismatch between the library used in the butterknife and ur application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some libraries that have dependencies on the same library **but** different version. Check the [dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree) and [exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765656/5132804) the unwanted one

Answer (score 0):

You need press **ALT+ENTER** and up new version **appcompat-v7:25.3.0**