# Groovy @Slf4j annotation: "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings"

Tags: gradle, groovy, annotations, logback, slf4j

There are several questions on this subject but none that I could find relates to the Groovy `@Slf4j` "AST" annotation. Which on the face of it is not just convenient but gives you conditional execution of stuff depending on log level.

In my book, Groovy in Action, it says:

> Injects an Slf4j logger as a static final org.slf4j.Logger into your
>   class and initializes it using
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(class) . The LogBack framework uses
>   SLF4J as the underlying logger, so LogBack users should use @Slf4j

And that's what I'm doing.  I've got this in my gradle.build

```
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1'
```

... and I've rustled up a simple logback-test.xml.

But each time I run a test class with this annotation, or run the app directly, I'm getting:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in [jar:file:/D:/apps/...
>   fbb0e/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/apps/...
>   eca4e/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. 
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

... in particular this is sort of "polluting" my `stderr` output of my tests.

I tried manually deleting the slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar file ... but it got automatically regenerated next Gradle task.

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is one of the authors of this book. Yes, **THE** Jon Skeet.  Help Jon!

**in answer to the two comments** (thanks!)
... here is the output

```
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.6.0-alpha-2
+--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.11
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
+--- org.apache.odftoolkit:simple-odf:0.8.2-incubating
|    +--- org.apache.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.8.11-incubating
|    |    +--- org.apache.odftoolkit:taglets:0.8.11-incubating
|    |    +--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
|    |    +--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 -> 1.4.01
|    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-core:2.11.2
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.22
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:1.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.22
|    |    |    |    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
|    |    |    +--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
|    |    +--- net.rootdev:java-rdfa:0.4.2
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:0.9.1 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.6 -> 1.7.22
|    |    \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.0
|    |         +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2
|    |         |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |         |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1 -> 3.2.2
|    |         +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8.1
|    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |         \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    +--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1 -> 2.11.0 (*)
|    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 -> 1.4.01
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:6.+ -> 6.6.2
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:6.+ -> 6.6.2
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:6.6.2
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:6.+ -> 6.6.2
|    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:6.6.2
|    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:6.6.2
|    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:6.6.2
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.5 -> 2.6
\--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1
     +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.1
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22
```

Clearly,  Szymon Stepniak's comment is right. Now I just have to find out how to exclude this use of log4j by the culprit (odftoolkit) package ... and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle) I find someone wanting to do precisely that.

Comment: Could you add the output of `./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime` to your question?

Comment: One (or many) dependency adds `slf4j-log4j12` to your classpath. The solution is to track it down and exclude it in `build.gradle`. Without knowing your dependencies we can't tell you which one of them adds `slf4j-log4j12` to the classpath.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Thanks - see edit.  Would you like to turn your comment into an answer? Otherwise I'll make one myself... (or maybe I should delete/mark as a dupe?)

Comment: @mikerodent Cool, awesome we could help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message you see in the console has actually nothing to do with `@Slf4j` annotation used in your code - it just simplifies adding `log` field to your class. Your problem is caused by multiple `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` classes found in your classpath. To fix it you have to firstly check your dependencies tree using:

```
gradle dependencies --configuration runtime
```

It will display a full tree of all dependencies. Than you can track down which dependency is adding additional logger to your classpath. As you mentioned in the comment, in your case it is `org.apache.odftoolkit:simple-odf:0.8.2-incubating` adding `log4j` dependency.

Knowing that you have to exclude transitive dependencies of group `org.slf4j` and `log4j` that come with `org.apache.odftoolkit:simple-odf:0.8.2-incubating`. Define this dependency in your `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
compile ("org.apache.odftoolkit:simple-odf:0.8.2-incubating") {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    exclude group: 'log4j'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest, although Szymon Stepniak's solution is probably the best way to go, there is another solution, which I essentially obtained from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle):

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

... I suppose this might have the advantage that you don't have to deal with the exclusions for each offending package individually ... ?