# Android Studio error: Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio

> Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.android.volley.BuildConfig, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

I'm facing this problem when I try to use volley library for my main app module and my project also has a `LinkedIn` module which also has volley library.

Thanks in advance for the solution.

Comment: Can you share your gradle file

Comment: You can try this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765656/5901903

Comment: @Swapon I'm also facing the same issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue.

I solved this issue by following steps

1. Remove the `.jar` file of **Volley** from app and **LinkedIn** module
2. Adding **same dependency version** of Volley library in both the module.