# Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging

Tags: java, android, spring

Duplicate class. How to solve this? Build failed, thanks.

```
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.9.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.9.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
```

> Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.Log found in modules
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and
>   spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
>   (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.9.RELEASE) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory found in modules
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and
>   spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
>   (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.9.RELEASE) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1 found in modules
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and
>   spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
>   (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.9.RELEASE) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog found in modules
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and
>   spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
>   (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.9.RELEASE) Duplicate class
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog found in modules
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and
>   spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
>   (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.9.RELEASE)

Comment: You can exclude certain dependency from another dependency. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle

Answer (score 0):

```
 Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.8.RELEASE)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1 found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.8.RELEASE)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.8.RELEASE)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog found in modules jetified-commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2) and jetified-spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.8.RELEASE)
```

The class files in the two packages in the dependencies are duplicated, delete either one to solve this issue. You can rename one .jar as .zip to delete .class files