# gradle exclude a transitive dependency

Tags: gradle

I am trying to exclude a transitive dependency in gradle

```
    implementation (('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.3.0'), {
        exclude 'org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:5.18.3'
    })
```

I am seeing this error

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project

> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:5.18.3] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.apache.kafka', name='kafka-streams', version='2.3.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

I am using gradle 5.6.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)

Comment: no, I am explicitly looking to get this example working. The solutions in the link above deal with "compile", which is no longer the recommended way to use gradle

Comment: Why the double parentheses? Also please provide a minimal complete build.gradle file, as the cause of the error might be in surrounding lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Reference*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps)

Groovy:

```groovy
implementation('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.kafka', module: 'kafka-streams'
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
implementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.3.0") {
    exclude(group = "org.apache.kafka", module = "kafka-streams")
}
```

As you can see the exclude can only support `group` and `module` arguments - not the single string format `group:module:version`.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation ('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.3.0'){
   //transitive dependency:org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:5.18.3
   exclude group: 'org.rocksdb', module: 'rocksdbjni'
}
```