# Exclude Gradle transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to exclude a nested transitive dependency from the gradle build. The dependency structure looks like

+---org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.33.0-custom

```
+---META-INF/maven/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/
```

[image]

I excluded the dependency by following the accepted solution from [gradle exclude a transitive dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868920/gradle-exclude-a-transitive-dependency) but it didnt work for me.

```
implementation('core-lib:tag') {
    implementation('org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.33.0-custom') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
    }
}
```

This doesnt exclude the dependency. When I change this to `*` the dependencies are still not excluded.

```
implementation('core-lib:tag') {
    implementation('org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.33.0-custom') {
        exclude group: '*', module:'*'
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how can i exclude this dependency? Its pulling in an older version.

Answer (score 2):

it should be as below - optionally you can add module
see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

```
implementation('core-lib:tag') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
```

Comment: I also tried this but it removes all the dependencies of org.apache.commons from core-lib which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the one in the image, all you need to do is specify that one specifically. If you leave it off, it will exclude the entire group; so you add the specific name so it only excludes that one.

```
implementation('core-lib:tag') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-compress'
}
```