# How to depend Spring with Jackson and without Web

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jackson, dependency-management

How to properly connect jackson to a standalone SpringBoot application without unnecessary dependencies (web)?

Java 18

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.7.5-SNAPSHOT'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
  annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

[image: External Libraries in IDEA]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle exclude a transitive dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868920/gradle-exclude-a-transitive-dependency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot's auto-configuration for Jackson requires `spring-web` as it's the Spring Framework module that contains the infrastructure for configuring and creating a Jackson `ObjectMapper`. If you really don't want a `spring-web` dependency in your application, you could replace the dependency on `spring-boot-starter-json` with a direct dependency on Jackson instead, however you will then have to configure and create the `ObjectMapper` yourself as Spring Boot will no longer do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom `jackson` standalone configuration.

It only contains what I need, but you could easily copy the bits in the `JacksonAutoConfiguration` for the `jacksonProperties` or anything else that you need and add them here. And then remove the `JacksonAutoConfiguration` class and use the code snippet below.

I just wanted to keep it simple because mine was for a `redis` synchronization service.

The optimal solution would be to rewrite the code in `JacksonAutoConfiguration`  and drop the `Jackson2ObjectMapper` and use `JsonMapper.builder()` instead and then they could drop the `spring-web` dependency entirely.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonStandaloneConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonOjectMapper(ObjectProvider<Module> provider) {
        // All modules declared as beans anywhere else
        List<Module> modulesToInstall = provider.stream().toList();
        Builder builder = JsonMapper.builder();
        ObjectMapper mapper = configure(builder);
        registerModules(mapper, modulesToInstall);
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper configure(Builder builder) {
        return builder //
                // Spring boot defaults
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) //
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS) //
                // Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder defaults
                .disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION) //
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) //
                .build();
    }

    private static void registerModules(ObjectMapper mapper, List<Module> modulesToInstall) {
        MultiValueMap<Object, Module> modulesToRegister = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(modulesToRegister);
        modulesToInstall.forEach(module -> registerModule(module, modulesToRegister));
        List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Module> nestedModules : modulesToRegister.values()) {
            modules.addAll(nestedModules);
        }
        mapper.registerModules(modules);
    }

    private static void registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(MultiValueMap<Object, Module> modulesToRegister) {
        // Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder defaults (You could add these as beans and remove this method entirely)
        registerModule(new Jdk8Module(), modulesToRegister);
        registerModule(new JavaTimeModule(), modulesToRegister);
//      registerModule(new JodaModule(), modulesToRegister);
//      registerModule(new KotlinModule(), modulesToRegister);
    }

    private static void registerModule(Module module, MultiValueMap<Object, Module> modulesToRegister) {
        if (module.getTypeId() == null) {
            modulesToRegister.add(SimpleModule.class.getName(), module);
        } else {
            modulesToRegister.set(module.getTypeId(), module);
        }
    }

}
```