# Error after adding boofcv-core to Android: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf

Tags: android, boofcv

I`m trying to add *boofcv-core* library to my Android project.
*boofcv-android* works fine but *boofcv-core* generates the following error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.17.3.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.3) and protobuf-javalite-3.14.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0)...`

The code at *build.gradle*:

```
...
configurations {
//    compile.exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf' // when uncommented, causes other errors
    all*.exclude group: "xmlpull", module: "xmlpull"
    all*.exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-compress"
    all*.exclude group: "com.thoughtworks.xstream", module: "commons-compress"
}

dependencies {
    ['boofcv-android', 'boofcv-core'].each {
        String a -> implementation group: 'org.boofcv', name: a, version: '0.37'
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved:
`protobuf-java`(dependency inside `boofcv-core`) and `protobuf-javalite`(dependency inside `firebase`) cant exist together- [full explanation here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/8104#issuecomment-887076083).
After generating a dependency tree(`./gradlew app:dependencies`), I noticed that only `boofcv-geo` and `boofcv-recognition` (libraries inside `boofcv-core` - see [link](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/tree/SNAPSHOT/main)) depend on `protobuf-java`. I have no need in these 2 libraries so I excluded them from compilation.
At *app/build.gradle*, add:

```
...
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'org.boofcv',module: 'boofcv-recognition' //<-- added
    compile.exclude group: 'org.boofcv',module: 'boofcv-geo' //<-- added
    all*.exclude group: "xmlpull", module: "xmlpull"
    all*.exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-compress"
    all*.exclude group: "com.thoughtworks.xstream", module: "commons-compress"
}
...
```

And then the error disappears.

Comment: This is just a compile time exclusion? Removing 'boofcv-geo' entirely would break a lot of applications. When you specify a dependency via implements you can exclude a transitive dependency.

Comment: Thank you for maintaining this great library!
Could you explain the second sentence about transitive dependency?

Comment: basically you should remove the protobuf dependency when you do `implementation(...)`. That way you won't end up with two protobuf libs at runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868920/gradle-exclude-a-transitive-dependency

Comment: @lessthanoptimal It has caused a whole new error:

    implementation "org.boofcv:boofcv-android:0.31"

    implementation (("org.boofcv:boofcv-core:0.38"), {
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    })
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class boofcv.abst.geo.calibration.CalibrateMonoPlanar found in modules boofcv-calibration-0.31.jar (org.boofcv:boofcv-calibration:0.31) and boofcv-geo-0.38.jar (org.boofcv:boofcv-geo:0.38)`