# Disable import of Android SDK/Support Libraries

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am trying to re-build an unpacked apk, because it was unpacked the required libraries are already included, deleting the prepacked libraries would be feasible if it weren't for the fact that some of the dependencies seem to be missing when I build with them deleted.  I could individually sort through and pick out only the ones that aren't added on build and delete the rest, but it seems like it would be easier to exclude the android support libraries from being included at all.  Can/how can this be done in Android Studio/with Gradle?

Comment: Which libraries is annoying you, exactly?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue I get a conflict from ```android.app```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible it is probably not documented because it goes against usual ownership securities. If this APK is yours, you can do this operation from the sources. **If it is not, you should not be doing this operation**.

However, you can exclude the desired libraries from the rebuild by avoiding to depend on them, or by excluding them explicitly, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle).

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude group: "...", module: "..."
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why I should not be doing it if it is not mine?

Comment: Usually it is because the APK is provided with a proprietary license that forbids you to produce derived works using the contents of the software. It all depends on the license of the app.

Comment: No, generally it prohibits the redistribution of the app and distribution of derivative works.  Writing in a book is distinct from republishing a book you annotated.

Comment: And, what would I exclude, to exclude all android support libraries?

Comment: The list is pretty long, and I do not know them like that. In your place I would find them by trial and error... It is long but you only have to do it once.

Comment: Oh I see, so there is no way to exclude all support libraries?

Comment: You could try with `exclude group: "com.android.support"`, but it is possible that it excludes too much.