# Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified android

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetifier

I am using two libraries in my app 1 aar and another gradle dependency.
I am getting this error on building release build

```
Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-android-sdk-1.7.26-runtime (com.cashfree.pg:android-sdk:1.7.26) and jetified-adsdk-AN-1.15.16-runtime (adsdk-AN-1.15.16.aar)
```

This is my build gradle app level

```
implementation 'com.cashfree.pg:android-sdk:1.7.26'
implementation files('libs/adsdk-AN-1.15.16.aar')

//Dependencies used by all payment modes
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
```

Not able to understand this `a.a` class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was due to proguard rules of the SDK
Add below rules to SDK proguard and it worked then

```
-repackageclasses 'com.example'
-allowaccessmodification
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keeppackagenames doNotKeepAThing
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've got a couple of classes with the same name when obfuscation is done.

a.a is an obfuscated name, you can find how it works and how to extract the mapping file for the obfuscated classes [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace). You can determine the package name from the mapping file (it will be like a.a -> some.package.name) and exclude it if the next step won't help you.

Check properties in your gradle.properties file, it should be like that.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If it is - then you'll have to explicitly exclude these classes. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle) answer.