# How to exclude some libraries from Spring boot fat jar file using Gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I want to exclude certain jar files from Spring boot fat executable jar file.  I want to exclude following files :
prosys-opc-ua-sdk-evaluation-4.10.6-24.jar
and following BouncyCastle libraries.

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.73'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.73'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcutil-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.73'
```

My build.gradle file is like this.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//springBoot {
//    mainClass = "opcuaserver.OpcUaServerApplication"
//}
//
//jar {
//    manifest {
//        attributes(
//                'Main-Class': 'opcuaserver.OpcUaServerApplication'
//        )
//    }
//}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'

    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.16'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-nio
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore-nio', version: '4.4.16'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.9.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.6.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.73'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.73'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcutil-jdk18on
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.73'

    implementation files('lib/prosys-opc-ua-sdk-evaluation-4.10.6-24.jar')
//    implementation files('lib/bcpkix-jdk18on-173.jar')
//    implementation files('lib/bcprov-jdk18on-173.jar')
//    implementation files('lib/bcutil-jdk18on-173.jar')
//    implementation files('lib/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar')
    implementation files('lib/Utils-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-common-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/connection-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-log-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/LogManager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/TinyLog-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-licensing-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/jniwrap-3.12.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-messaging-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-communication-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/GoogleProtocolBuffer_2.6.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-data-provider-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emdb-entities-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emdb-model-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-local-data-cache-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-data-writers-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-data-provider-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-entities-2.0.0.1.jar')


}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)