# how to remove com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0@aar from external libraries of project in android studio

Tags: android, dependency-management, google-ads-api, android-library, android-sdk-2.3

I have removed -->  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:11.4.0' dependency from build.gradle and also excluded it from all other dependencies present in project, but still getting com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0@aar in external libraries of project.
I want to remove this sdk permanently but I am not able to do so, please provide me some solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765656/6819340?